# How to Implement "fluent constructors" inside visualforce page data iterator?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable, custom-controller, iteration

I am trying to put together a custom controller class implementing the fluid interface builder pattern. Said class does compile, and my question is how can it be implemented inside a VisualForce page's data iterator such as pageBlockTable.

The controller class works as expected when tested inside the anonymous window; here's the tested code:

```
ContactsListController ctrller = ContactsListController.objInstance();
ctrller.sortBy('FirstName').sortOrder('DESC').RecCount(5);

ctrller.getContacts();
```

**This is what I have tried**:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{! contacts.objInstance().SortOrder('DESC').RecCount(3) }" var="ct">...
```

and this is the error message I get:

```
ContactsListController 0 Syntax erro. Extra '.'
```

I ran out of ideas; can anybody shed some light on this?

Thank you all for your time and help.

Comment: move the fluent expression to a public method in the controller and reference the method in the VF page

Answer (score 0):

It can't. Visualforce does not support parameters for functions in the way you describe. Any such logic would have to be carried out in the controller or extension code for the page.